# 404 not found from angular frontend in production

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, ssl-certificate, http-status-code-404

I have 2 sub domain for 2 API application, in 2 vnet and they have the same certificates. One backend is developed in php and deployed in Apache server and the another one is developend in .Net 6 and deployed in IIS 10.  Now I have a angular 14 application which consume these backend api. The problem is when one api returns success status then the another api throws 404 error. I am not sure where is the problem.

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eVWP.png)

In local environment I can get responses from both API, but in production I get 404 error for the 2nd api call. I am trying to solve the issue.

Comment: Please post details about the 404 error, if not you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to view detailed error information.